# WP_Query: Why is sticky post not first item in loop?

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, sticky-post

I've got a custom `WP_Query` loop based of meta_value variables:

```
$meta_cat = get_sub_field('category');
$posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat' => $meta_cat,
    'posts_per_page' => get_sub_field('recent_ppp'),
) );
```

But somehow when I'll make a post sticky it isn't shown as the first item in the while loop.

I know `ignore_sticky_posts` is default set to false so I won't bother changing it. Also tried looking in de [order_by documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) if some value is related to sticky post but it isn't.

Although The `order_by => 'post__in'` might be close:

> Preserve post ID order given in the post__in array

But when I set `post__in => get_options('sticky_posts')` **only** the sticky post is showing.

Is this even possible without building two custom loops (one handeling the sticky posts and the other for the other posts? That would be really bad, because not all categories contain sticky posts.

Comment: Not the answer, but you have a typo in `$$meta_cat`

Comment: I've changed a few thing for this post. So just a little typo, thanks though ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look ate the source code where stickies are included, we find the following condition before `WP_Query` carries on to include sticky posts

```
if (    $this->is_home 
     && $page <= 1 
     && is_array($sticky_posts) 
     && !empty($sticky_posts)  
     && !$q['ignore_sticky_posts'] 
) {
```

The big game player is the `is_home` condition. Conditionals inside `WP_Query` is set according to the arguments passed to it, and not the page where the query happens. Because you pass `cat` as an argument, `is_home` will be set to false, and `is_category` will be set to true. Because `is_home` is set to false, the above condition fails and stickies are not included.

### POSSIBLE WORK-AROUND - <strike>*Untested*</strike>

What we can do, is to manually set `is_home` to true via `pre_get_posts`. All we need to do is to pass `'wpse_is_home' => true,` to your custom `WP_Query` instance

Then we run our `pre_get_posts` action as follow

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    if ( true === $q->get( 'wpse_is_home' ) ) 
        $q->is_home = true;
});
```

### EDIT

We would probably only want to show stickies which has relevance to the queried category. In that case, we should remove stickies that does not belong to the specific queried category

We can try the following, still inside our `pre_get_posts` action

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q )
{
    remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );

    if ( true !== $q->get( 'wpse_is_home' ) )
        return;

    // Make sure get_sub_field exists, if not, bail
    if ( !function_exists( 'get_sub_field' ) )
        return;

    // Lets query everything to keep code clean
    $meta_cat = get_sub_field( 'category' ); // Copied from your code
    $meta_cat = filter_var( $meta_cat, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
    // Make sure we have a value, if not, bail
    if ( !$meta_cat )
        return;

    $q->set( 'cat', $meta_cat );

    // Set pagination if recent_ppp exists
    $ppp = get_sub_field( 'recent_ppp');
    $ppp = filter_var( $ppp, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
    if ( $ppp )
        $q->set( 'posts_per_page', $ppp );      

    // Set is_home to true 
    $q->is_home = true;

    // Get all stickies
    $stickies = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
    // Make sure we have stickies, if not, bail
    if ( !$stickies )
        return;

    // Query the stickies according to category
    $args = [
        'post__in'            => $stickies,
        'posts_per_page'      => -1,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, // Ignore stickies
        'cat'                 => $meta_cat,
        'orderby'             => 'post__in',
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'fields'              => 'ids' // Get only post ID's
    ];
    $valid_sticky_ids = get_posts( $args );

    // Make sure we have valid ids
    if ( !$valid_sticky_ids ) {
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $stickies );
        return;
    }

    // Remove these ids from the sticky posts array
    $invalid_ids = array_diff( $stickies, $valid_sticky_ids );

    // Check if we still have ids left in $invalid_ids
    if ( !$invalid_ids )
        return;

    // Lets remove these invalid ids from our query
    $q->set( 'post__not_in', $invalid_ids );
});
```

Before we run our custom query, we would need to make sure that `get_sub_field` exists, and most importantly, that `get_sub_field( 'category' )` is set and valid. This will avoid catastrophic failure which will lead to all posts being returned, regardless.

Your `WP_Query` can look something like this as we only need to pass `'wpse_is_home' => true`:

```
if (    function_exists( 'get_sub_field' )
     && filter_var( get_sub_field( 'category' ), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT )
) {
    $args = [
        'wpse_is_home' => true
    ];
    $posts_array = new WP_Query( $args ); // DO NOT USE $posts

    // Run your loop as normal
}
```

**LAST EDIT**

Code is tested and working as expected

Comment: Please see my edit. I hope this is what you need

Comment: Yesterday I'll already implemented the basic pre_get_posts action, which also did work. I will try the advanced one this afternoon. Thanks for helping out! :)

Comment: My pleasure, glad the first edition works. Let me know if you encounter any issues with the advance code. I did test it, but my local install is quite small, so it tends to miss stuff. Enjoy and good luck on your project ;-)