# WP Query with sticky posts and tax_query

Tags: wp-query, taxonomy, sticky-post

I have this query;

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
        ));
```

Which correctly places sticky posts at the beginning. However, when I add a taxonomy query like so;

```
$posts = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'category',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'news'
                    )
        ));
```

Sticky posts will no longer be prepended in the results. I have tried including the `ignore_sticky_posts => 0` parameter but I have had no success.

How can I get sticky posts working with a taxonomy query? And yes, my sticky posts belongs to that term.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WP\_Query: Why is sticky post not first item in loop?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/219501/wp-query-why-is-sticky-post-not-first-item-in-loop)

Comment: @Sumit sticky posts does work with custom loops, it just depends on the exact arguments passed to `WP_Query` ;-)

Comment: @Sumit with the arguments passed in the first block, this causes `is_home` internally to0 be set to true. Remember, the arguments passed to a query decides the value of the condional tags

Comment: Weird, because sticky posts are definitely working for me in that first query. If I unsticky in the WP Admin, the post falls back to its normal position. Otherwise when sticky, it's at the top.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I am sorry you mean `is_home()` will be true for first query in OP ?

Comment: @Brian Yes, stickies will work in the first query and not in the second query. Check the post I marked as duplicate

Comment: @Sumit correct ;-)

Comment: @Sumit quickly run both queries and then do `var_dump( $posts->is_home )`

Comment: Holy .... :O I was living in dark :D I tested it and yes correct. I need to check how `is_home` set to true in query class. Thank you very much Pieter :) I thought `is_home` is only true in main query and never in secondary query.

Comment: So the other post has a solution that involves using a filter to override `is_home`, which I'll end up doing. But now I can't help but wonder why WP doesn't support this out of the box.

Comment: I found it why it is `true` [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/query.php#L1774) Thanks @PieterGoosen I am learning a lot from you :)